# how can i fix malformed string output when python server gets data through gRPC?

Tags: python, go, grpc

making server(python), client(golnag)

When the client sends an array of strings via gRPC

the server prints strange data.

#### example `.proto` below

```
message HiRequest {
    repeated string hi = 1;
}
```

#### golang code below

```
input := new(pb.HiRequest)
input.Hi = append(input.Hi, "안녕")
input.Hi = append(input.Hi, "おはよう")
input.Hi = append(input.Hi, "Hello")
// Send to server
```

#### python code below

```
print(request.hi)
```

#### expected output is

```
hi: "안녕"
hi: "おはよう"
hi: "Hello"
```

#### but the actual output is

```
hi: "\354\225\210\353\205\225"
hi: "\343\201\212\343\201\257\343\202\210\343\201\206"
hi: "Hello"
```

can anyone tell me the reason? and the solution plz

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens is that you send Unicode characters and they are encoded to 1-byte characters. Assuming that your received value is of type bytes, just do:

```
value.decode()
```

For example:

```
value = b"\343\201\212\343\201\257\343\202\210\343\201\206" # creating a bytes type string
print(value.decode())
>>> おはよう
```

**Edit:**

For any other people stumbling on that:
If what I've said doesn't work for you, change the value in your `.proto` file to bytes from string

Comment: Thanks. but it says no `decode()` func. `Exception calling application: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: @JS_Kim Try using bytes in your `.proto` file and then try my solution again, I think that it might work

Comment: @JS_Kim Awesome :D glad I could help :)